# Will I be billed if I do not have any projects on my Google Developers Console?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I just received an email from the Google Cloud Storage team, which states:

> Hello Google Cloud Storage User,
>
> Please be advised that, beginning July 14, 2015, Google will begin charging the following fees for Google Cloud Storage:
>
> - $0.01 per GB of data transferred between buckets located in different regions of the same continent
> - Egress rates per GB of data transferred between buckets located on different continents
>
> Until then, you will be able to view your current usage in the billing details for your project in order to help you estimate the impact of these changes on your monthly spend.
>
> For additional information and examples of this billing charge, please visit https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-regions
>
> -- The Google Cloud Storage Team
>
> Google Inc. 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043
>
> You have received this mandatory service announcement to update you about important changes to Google Cloud Platform or your account.

I just want to know if I'll be charged any money if I do not have any projects in my Google Developers Console?

I had one project which I deleted instantly, but it's still showing under the "projects pending deletion" section.

Here is how my console currently looks like:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: you only get charged for usage, so you could have 100 projects, and if you don't do nothing then you'll pay for nothing

Comment: @JaimeGómez  sir I am just a little boy..I made a website using wordpress once and in that a plugin led me to the way of creating a project and all that stuff.Now I have deleted the project and but it still appears under the "projects pending deletion" section.how to remove from there?

Comment: it'll disappear when the project is deleted, probably 7 days after the request, don't worry about it :)

Comment: Thank you very much sir...will contact you if needed...how do you hhank people here...isnt there a thanks button like xda?@JaimeGómez

Comment: @JaimeGómez  Okk sir didi it..

Comment: When I read this email I thought it was a phishing scam. Silly Google!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only get charged for usage, so you could have 100 projects, and if you don't do nothing then you'll pay for nothing.

The "project pending deletion" will disappear when as soon as it's deleted, probably 7 days after the request, don't worry about it.

Comment: I think the number of project per account is limited. The old view for AppEngine (available here: https://appengine.google.com/) shows "You have 19 applications remaining". Every new project reduces this value. The answer is of course right, you will not pay for any project unless you enabled billing. Just wanted to put my two cents.

Comment: Yeah I exaggerated hehe, but you can have more, every time you enable billing in a project you free up a slot.

Comment: @tomrozb  how do i check whether billing is enabled.??

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan You can check it here: https://console.developers.google.com/billing/